# Confusing Port Forwarding Status

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I’m not an expert yet on Networking and I’m a bit confused if how port forwarding works on router.

Like for example I opened a port for my VPN Server on my Raspberry Pi and the specific port which I port forwarded from the router to access my VPN Server on my Raspberry Pi on home works now on outside networks like at my office or public Wi-Fis.

But the thing is when I try to check at `canyouseeme.org` the specific port that I opened in my router for my VPN server at home its says error or closed. I tried several port checker sites but they are all the same. But the good thing is I can connect to my VPN server at home even though it says closed on portchecker tools. Why?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are able to connect to your VPN, which is internal to your network, from outside of your intranet then you have successfully forwarded all traffic on that port to the machine hosting the VPN service.

Comment: Likely security policies or the service simply isn't responding to those requests for some reason. For instance, the router I use at home blocks ICMP echo requests by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the  VPN software you are using uses the UDP protocol (or maybe GRE), which does do not have a "handshake" like the more commonly used TCP protocol.

The sites you were looking to test from most likely were testing TCP, so they would not pick up UDP. (Canyouseeme.org only lists TCP ports/protocols)